# Angular - Cancel prior HTTP request if a later request fails

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-httpclient

When a user updates an item in my database, a record of that update needs to be saved inside a history for that item. Basically, I have a history table in my database that keeps track of a certain item's life-cycle.

I am making the change to this item via a PUT request in my service and then separately calling a different POST endpoint to add that action to the history table. This has me concerned because if the first PUT request succeeds, the history POST may fail due to a spotty internet connection, etc... This would not be ideal as an accurate history is vital to the application.

I essentially would need a way to rollback the initial PUT if the history POST fails.

I would love if there was an angular way to accomplish this. If not, would it be more sensible to just write the POST history into the PUT endpoint SQL query?

Here is a basic version of what I have right now:

```
this._itemService
    .updateItem(updateObject)
    .pipe(flatMap(result1 => this._historyService.postHistory(historyObject)))
    .pipe(take(1))
    .subscribe(result2 => {
       // Notify user that the item was updated.
    });
```

Comment: Would make much more sense if you have a server side code to handle push event notifications. Or message broker if your history service is on it's own.

Comment: I think your server should handle this sort of logic. Because the 'reset' that you want to accomplish as well could also fail. So what would you do then?
If your server can manage a message/socket connect that would probably be an alternate approach.

Comment: I think that would make sense as well. It will require a few more endpoints, but it would guarantee that one will not be able to succeed without the other. Thank you both for taking the time to give some input.